# How to pass an arrylist of LatLng from one activity to another

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I want to pass an `ArrayList` of `LatLng` variables from one `Activity` to another through button click.

The one available for `String` is not working Please help me out....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as an ArrayList of Parcelable objects.

```
// Put the coordinates
ArrayList<LatLng> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("coordinates", coordinates);

// Get the coordinates
coordinates = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("coordinates");
```

To pass the bundle you need to the intent object you use to invoke the other activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the SecondActivity's onCreate you fetch the bundle:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> coordinates = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("coordinates");
```

Comment: Could you please show me how to declare it in the first activity and in the second activity.

Comment: My main activity is MapsActivity.java and the second activity is SecondActivity.java

Comment: @NavneetAnand do you call `startActivity` to start the SecondActivity?

Comment: on create of each activity you have to pass and retrieve.

Comment: b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
       public void onClick(View v){
             Intent intent = new                     Intent(MapsActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);   
              startActivity(intent);
           }});

Comment: @NavneetAnand you're welcome :) mark this answer as correct if your problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should parceble class or getParceble()

check following link:[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830894/passing-arraylist-between-activities)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790499/passing-arraylist-of-objects-between-activities)